# Readtable() with differing number of columns - Julia

Tags: csv, dataframe, julia

I'm trying to read a CSV file into a DataFrame using readtable(). There is an unfortunate issue with the CSV file in that if the last *x* columns of a given row are blank, instead of generating that number of commas, it just ends the line. For example, I can have:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
item1,item2,,item4
item5
```

Notice how in the third line, there is only one entry. Ideally, I would like readtable to fill the values for Col2, Col3, and Col4 with NA, NA, and NA; however, because of the lack of commas and therefore lack of empty strings, readtable() simply sees this as a row that doesn't match the number of columns. If I run readtable() in Julia with the sample CSV above, I get the error "Saw 2 Rows, 2 columns, and 5 fields, * Line 1 has 6 columns". If I add in 3 commas after item5, then it works.

Is there any way around this, or do I have to fix the CSV file?

Answer (score 3):

If the CSV parsing doesn't need too much quote logic, it is easy to write a special purpose parser to handle the case of missing columns. Like so:

```
function bespokeread(s)
  headers = split(strip(readline(s)),',')
  ncols = length(headers)
  data = [String[] for i=1:ncols]
  while !eof(s)
    newline = split(strip(readline(s)),',')
    length(newline)<ncols && append!(newline,["" for i=1:ncols-length(newline)])
    for i=1:ncols
      push!(data[i],newline[i])
    end
  end
  return DataFrame(;OrderedDict(Symbol(headers[i])=>data[i] for i=1:ncols)...)
end
```

Then the file:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
item1,item2,,item4
item5
```

Would give:

```
julia> df = bespokeread(f)
2×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ Col1    │ Col2    │ Col3 │ Col4    │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ "item1" │ "item2" │ ""   │ "item4" │
│ 2   │ "item5" │ ""      │ ""   │ ""      │
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Dan Getz is nice, but it converts everything to strings.

The following solution instead "fill" the gap and write a new file (in a memory-efficient way) that can then be normally imported using readtable():

```
function fillAll(iF,oF,d=",")
    open(iF, "r") do i
        open(oF, "w") do o # "w" for writing
            headerRow = strip(readline(i))
            headers = split(headerRow,d)
            nCols =  length(headers)
            write(o, headerRow*"\n") 
            for ln in eachline(i)
                nFields = length(split(strip(ln),d))
                write(o, strip(ln))
                [write(o,d) for y in 1:nCols-nFields] # write delimiters to match headers
                write(o,"\n") 
            end
        end
    end
end

fillAll("data.csv","data_out.csv",";")
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better: just use [CSV.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl).

```
julia> f = IOBuffer("Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4\nitem1,item2,,item4\nitem5"); # or the filename

julia> CSV.read(f)
2×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ Col1    │ Col2    │ Col3  │ Col4    │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ "item1" │ "item2" │ #NULL │ "item4" │
│ 2   │ "item5" │ #NULL   │ #NULL │ #NULL   │
```